# Cesiumjs: How to update UrlTemplateImageryProvider's url?

Tags: cesiumjs

I have UrlTemplateImageryProvider Layer on my Cesium earth.

```
var imageryProvider = new Cesium.UrlTemplateImageryProvider({
    url: 'servicerul?styleset=hybrid&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}'
});
var imageryLayer = new Cesium.ImageryLayer(imageryProvider, {
    maximumTerrainLevel: 20 
});
layerCollections.add(imageryLayer);
```

Now I need to change the UrlTemplateImageryProvider's url, which will be changed to **servicerul?styleset=*raster*&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}**, after clicking a button.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: This question was cross-posted to the [Cesium forums](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cesium-dev/GZrdj5AmNl4/zWta6wG0DAAJ)

Answer (score 1):

When the button is clicked, call [remove](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/ImageryLayerCollection.html#remove) or [removeAll](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/ImageryLayerCollection.html#removeAll) on your `layerCollections` to get rid of the old one.  Then run the same code you posted to create and add a layer with the new URL.